# How to add custom CSS properties to datepicker days with beforeShowDay?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I know how to add CSS classes to specific days with beforeShowDay, but I have no idea how to add an individual CSS property. I'm trying to color specific days with a hex value, and I don't know what those will be ahead of time so I can't just have classes for all of them.

Comment: Please see: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay

Comment: Read the question! I know how to add classes, just not individual properties. Adding classes is the only thing that's described in that section.

Comment: I did read the question. You add the classes to the day. Once the Class is added, you can use the CSS to style that class. If you want further assistance please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The issue is I don't know what color it's going to be ahead of time and I don't want to create millions of classes. Are you saying I should dynamically add the classes, keep track of them, and style them with Javascript?

Comment: It's not clear why you do not know what the Color will be ahead of time. You're being vague and there is no example of the code. If you need to apply a style to the element itself, this will be drastically harder to do. Let's start with which days get colors? The first of the month? The first of the Week? Every 15th of the month? Does every day of the month get a unique color?

Comment: Yeah, sorry for being vague - each day is going to have a different color, but it depends on what the user has entered. It's a sort of scheduling tool, and each day is a different shade of blue depending on how many people are available that day. Technically I could create lots of classes, but it just seemed like there would be an easier way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  var classSize = {
    "04192021": 12,
    "04202021": 2,
    "04212021": 20,
    "04222021": 6,
    "04232021": 4,
    "04262021": 9
  };
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      var dateString = $.datepicker.formatDate("mmddyy", date);
      var result = [
        date.getDay() == 0 || date.getDay() == 6 ? false : true,
        "blue-0",
        "0 Students Attending"
      ];
      if (classSize[dateString]) {
        result[1] = "blue-" + classSize[dateString];
        result[2] = classSize[dateString] + " Students Attending";
      }
      return result;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-datepicker td.blue-0 a {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.ui-datepicker td.blue-1 a {
  background: #EFEFFF;
}

.ui-datepicker td.blue-2 a {
  background: #DFDFFF;
}

.ui-datepicker td.blue-3 a {
  background: #CFCFFF;
}

.ui-datepicker td.blue-4 a {
  background: #BFBFFF;
}

.ui-datepicker td.blue-5 a {
  background: #AFAFFF;
}

.ui-datepicker td.blue-6 a {
  background: #9F9FFF;
}

.ui-datepicker td.blue-7 a {
  background: #8F8FFF;
}

.ui-datepicker td.blue-8 a {
  background: #7F7FFF;
}

.ui-datepicker td.blue-9 a {
  background: #6F6FFF;
}

.ui-datepicker td.blue-10 a {
  background: #5F5FFF;
  color: #fff;
}

.ui-datepicker td.blue-11 a {
  background: #4F4FFF;
  color: #fff;
}

.ui-datepicker td.blue-12 a {
  background: #3F3FFF;
  color: #fff;
}

.ui-datepicker td.blue-13 a {
  background: #2F2FFF;
  color: #fff;
}

.ui-datepicker td.blue-14 a {
  background: #1F1FFF;
  color: #fff;
}

.ui-datepicker td.blue-15 a {
  background: #0F0FFF;
  color: #fff;
}

.ui-datepicker td.blue-16 a {
  background: #0E0EFF;
  color: #fff;
}

.ui-datepicker td.blue-17 a {
  background: #0D0DFF;
  color: #fff;
}

.ui-datepicker td.blue-18 a {
  background: #0B0BFF;
  color: #fff;
}

.ui-datepicker td.blue-19 a {
  background: #0A0AFF;
  color: #fff;
}

.ui-datepicker td.blue-20 a {
  background: #0909FF;
  color: #fff;
}

.ui-datepicker td.blue-21 a {
  background: #0808FF;
  color: #fff;
}

.ui-datepicker td.blue-22 a {
  background: #0707FF;
  color: #fff;
}

.ui-datepicker td.blue-23 a {
  background: #0606FF;
  color: #fff;
}

.ui-datepicker td.blue-24 a {
  background: #0505FF;
  color: #fff;
}

.ui-datepicker td.blue-25 a {
  background: #0404FF;
  color: #fff;
}

.ui-datepicker td.blue-26 a {
  background: #0303FF;
  color: #fff;
}

.ui-datepicker td.blue-27 a {
  background: #0202FF;
  color: #fff;
}

.ui-datepicker td.blue-28 a {
  background: #0101FF;
  color: #fff;
}

.ui-datepicker td.blue-29 a {
  background: #0000FF;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

This is one way to do what you want to accomplish. With SASS you could make more variable styling. You may even be able to use things like CSS var().

There is no easy way to access the element as it's created dynamically. You can use `widget()` to do this; yet you have to run it often and repeatedly.

You might consider batches, so for example Less than 5, gets #EEF. 5 - 10 gets #DDF, 11 - 15 gets #CCF etc.

```js
$(function() {
  var classSize = {
    "04192021": 12,
    "04202021": 2,
    "04212021": 20,
    "04222021": 6,
    "04232021": 4,
    "04262021": 9,
    "04272021": 29,
    "04282021": 16,
    "04292021": 27,
    "04302021": 7
  };
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      var dateString = $.datepicker.formatDate("mmddyy", date);
      var result = [
        date.getDay() == 0 || date.getDay() == 6 ? false : true,
        "blue-0",
        "0 Students Attending"
      ];
      if (classSize[dateString]) {
        switch (true) {
          case classSize[dateString] < 5:
            result[1] = "blue-1";
            break;
          case classSize[dateString] < 10:
            result[1] = "blue-2";
            break;
          case classSize[dateString] < 15:
            result[1] = "blue-3";
            break;
          case classSize[dateString] < 20:
            result[1] = "blue-4";
            break;
          case classSize[dateString] < 25:
            result[1] = "blue-5";
            break;
          case classSize[dateString] < 30:
            result[1] = "blue-6";
            break;
          case classSize[dateString] >= 30:
            result[0] = false;
            result[1] = "blue-7";
            break;
        }
        result[2] = classSize[dateString] + " Students Attending";
      }
      return result;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-datepicker td.blue-0 a {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.ui-datepicker td.blue-1 a {
  background: #CCF;
}

.ui-datepicker td.blue-2 a {
  background: #AAF;
}

.ui-datepicker td.blue-3 a {
  background: #88F;
}

.ui-datepicker td.blue-4 a {
  background: #66F;
}

.ui-datepicker td.blue-5 a {
  background: #44F;
  color: #FFF;
}

.ui-datepicker td.blue-6 a {
  background: #22F;
  color: #FFF;
}

.ui-datepicker td.blue-7 a {
  background: #00F;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```